# Create stacked numpy array from grouped dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I need a fast function to create a single stacked numpy array from a Pandas dataframe after grouping the dataframe, with missing row values added. The output array should have a shape (n_unique_values_1, n_unique_values_2, ..., n_ungrouped_columns) for the group by columns 1, 2, .... Missing values should be filled nan, you may assume that all values can be safely handed as numeric.

Example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 1, 2],
    'b': [0, 1, 0],
    'c': [1, 1, 1],
    'd': [0, 0, 0]
})
grouped = df.groupby(['a', 'b']).agg(sum)
```

I need a function on `grouped` which returns a numpy array of shape `(df.a.nunique(), df.b.nunique(), n_ungrouped_cols)` (in this case, `(2, 2, 2)`). The function should work with arbitrary lengths of group, the returned array should have the axis in the same order as the groupby, and I need to run this on lots of millions of values in a pipeline that has a lot to do. Fast as hell would be very much appreciated. Oh, Pandas groupby preserves the ascending order of the unique values and that should not be lost. But if you can write this without using a grouped dataframe, go for it. Any imports (numba, etc.) that can make this quick are acceptable as long as they are from well maintained code bases.

The following can be used to create tests cases, and `test_case` in this example has missing rows:

```
def create_synthetic_df(len_df, n_uniques: list[int]):
    rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=2)
    if len(n_uniques) > 10:
        n_uniques = n_uniques[:10]
    dct = {}
    for col, n_unique in zip('abcdefghij', n_uniques):
        dct[col] = rng.integers(0, n_unique, size=len_df)
    return pd.DataFrame(dct)

n_uniques = (50, 3, 10, 10, 3)
test_case = create_synthetic_df(1000, n_uniques).groupby(['a', 'b', 'c']).agg(sum)

def my_func(grouped_df) -> np.ndarray:
    """Call the solution 'my_func'."""
    ...

# additional test cases, maybe not exhaustive

simple_case = my_func(grouped)  
expected = np.array([
    [[1, 0],
     [1, 0]],
    [[1, 0],
     [np.nan, np.nan]]
])
assert simple_case.shape == (2, 2, 2)
assert np.allclose(simple_case, expected, equal_nan=True)
assert my_func(test_case).shape == (50, 3, 10, 2)
```

Comment: the challenge for quickly making an array is that groups can vary in size, and need that `nan` padding.  Padding a list of arrays has been a topic of many SO.  I don't know it pandas has anything to make this easier (even if not faster).

Comment: Why is the value at expected[0, 1, 0] equal to 2? Seems like it should be 1. No cell of the df has a value of 2, and there are no duplicate a,b groups in this example.

Comment: Can you also provide your current implementation? Even if you are not satisfied with it, it would be very helpful for us to understand your requirements correctly.

Comment: And why does it have to have `ndarray` output? You'll lose your indices.

Comment: @NickODell That's because of a change that I forgot to carry over from notebook to SO. Thanks. I fixed the test case to match the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally this is a reindexing operation. There are trickier ways to do this, and I have not profiled this code; this is the "unsurprising" approach.

The second approach uses lower-level Numpy but I don't know which one will be faster. They are tested to be equivalent.

```py
import string
from typing import Sequence

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def create_synthetic_df(len_df: int, n_uniques: Sequence[int], seed: int = 2) -> pd.DataFrame:
    rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=seed)
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        data=1 + rng.integers(low=0, high=n_uniques, size=(len_df, len(n_uniques))),
        columns=tuple(string.ascii_lowercase[:len(n_uniques)]),
    )
    return df


def mi_reindex(df: pd.DataFrame, group_cols: list[str]) -> np.ndarray:
    totals: pd.DataFrame = df.groupby(group_cols).sum()
    uindex = [
        totals.index.unique(level=level).sort_values()
        for level in group_cols
    ]
    full_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables=uindex)

    aligned = totals.reindex(full_index)
    reshaped = aligned.values.reshape((
        *(
            u.size for u in uindex
        ),
        totals.columns.size,
    ))
    return reshaped


def np_unique(df: pd.DataFrame, group_cols: list[str]) -> np.ndarray:
    totals = df.groupby(group_cols).sum()

    uniques = [
        np.unique(
            ar=totals.index.get_level_values(col),
            return_inverse=True,
        )
        for col in group_cols
    ]

    dest = np.full(
        shape=(
            *(u.size for u, idx in uniques),
            totals.columns.size,
        ),
        fill_value=np.nan,
    )

    idx = tuple(i for u, i in uniques) + (slice(None),)
    dest[idx] = totals
    return dest


def test() -> None:
    simple_outputs = []
    big_outputs = []

    big_uniques = (50, 3, 10, 10, 3)
    big_input = create_synthetic_df(1000, big_uniques)
    simple_input = pd.DataFrame({
        'a': [1, 1, 2],
        'b': [0, 1, 0],
        'c': [1, 1, 1],
        'd': [0, 0, 0]
    })
    simple_output = np.array([
        [[1, 0],
         [1, 0]],  # this is not 2
        [[1, 0],
         [np.nan, np.nan]]
    ])

    for my_func in (mi_reindex, np_unique):
        actual = my_func(simple_input, ['a', 'b'])
        assert actual.shape == (2, 2, 2)
        assert np.allclose(actual, simple_output, equal_nan=True)
        simple_outputs.append(actual)

        actual = my_func(big_input, ['a', 'b', 'c'])
        assert actual.shape == (50, 3, 10, 2)
        big_outputs.append(actual)

    assert np.allclose(*simple_outputs, equal_nan=True)
    assert np.allclose(*big_outputs, equal_nan=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: Thank you. For `(len_df = 10_000, n_uniques=(50, 3, 10, 10, 3))` this times at 10ms, which is good enough. (And that includes doing the groupby op.)

Comment: I believe this to have a bug, and I have a second approach in the works. Please stand by.

Comment: @philosofool Please see edit; timings will be different

Comment: Thanks. I think I just spotted a bug, actually. I will get back later in a day or so (trying not to work too much this weekend!)